# Is it ok to use Cookies to store clear text user name like this?

Tags: security, http, session, cookies, session-cookies

For example, I want to use a cookie with **clear text** `username` to remember the user name. For security reasons, I will also add `session-id` and `session-token` for server-side verification.

I heard that cookie has some security issues. Is it ok to use it like this? What might be potential issues?

Comment: What do you intend to use the value of this cookie for? (Can a user make anything bad happen by setting it to something weird?)

Answer (score 0):

Securing cookies is important, and this link should get you started in the right direction: [Securing Cookies with HttpOnly and secure Flags](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/securing-cookies-httponly-secure-flags/)